# Three checkboxes, onClick of one others should be disabled using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm not getting how to do this.

I have three checkboxes and if i click one of them other checkboxes should be disabled. How can i achieve this using jQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" >
<input type="checkbox" name="box3" >
```

Help me in this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want 3 radio buttons? http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Comment: Yes, I don't want radio buttons. I need to do with checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/2WXKY/)**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', true); 
});
```

**[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2WXKY/1/)**

Alternatively, if you want to enable the checkboxes upon unselection, you could use this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend to use class names to reference DOM elements, this makes your code much cleaner and unobtrusive. This code is much more comprehensive and easier to maintain:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" class="check checker">
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="box3" class="check">
```

JS:

```
$('.checker').change(function() {
    $('.check').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

In this case you can change location of your checkboxes (`siblings` approach will break), their names (`[name^="box"]` will fail) without need to modify you JS code.

http://jsfiddle.net/4krnh/

Answer (score 0):

You may use :not() filter to exclude clicked checkbox.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $("input[type='checkbox']:not(input[name='"+name+"'])").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box1" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="box2" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="box3" >
</div>

$('input[name^="box"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(this).siblings().attr('checked', false);
})
```

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwqxd/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').not($(this)).attr("disabled", true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
         $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').not(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
     });
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AVEjt/267/)